# How to call function EnumPrinters from node-ffi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, node-ffi

According to MSDN, function EnumPrinters is  part of Winspool library:
Library - Winspool.lib
DLL - Winspool.drv
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692(v=vs.85).aspx

But there is no Winspool.dll.

I tried following code to create library in javascript:

```
var lib_test = new FFI.Library('Winspool', {
   'EnumPrinters': [ 'bool', [ ] ]
});
```

but got following error:

```
D:\print\ffi\node_modules\ffi\lib\dynamic_library.js:74
    throw new Error('Dynamic Linking Error: ' + err)
          ^
Error: Dynamic Linking Error: "Winspool.dll": The specified module could not be found.
    at new DynamicLibrary (D:\print\ffi\node_modules\ffi\lib\dynamic_library.js:74:11)
```

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/winspooldll-issue/89594fcf-ed04-4b16-bc93-9fbdbbdf4884

Comment: @user15 1. I can't rename dll on production environment. 2. It did not help on my PC.

Comment: Can you just download this file and put it on your production environment? say in directory with your code?

Comment: @user15 No, I can't. I can use only dll's that already exist on typical windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to specify the full path to winspool like this

```
var lib_test = new FFI.Library('C:\Windows\System32\winspool.dll', {
    'EnumPrinters': [ 'bool', [ ] ]
});
```

And you may have to rename winspool.drv to winspool.dll.